# Connection to Azure Cosmosdb failed using web socket

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a script that connects to CosmosDB to make some operations, am using CosmosDB as graphDB, however, am using a node module called gremlin-secure which connects to cosmosDB through web sockets, however, recently, I could not connect to the Database as below error

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: unexpected server response (200)
>       at ClientRequest._req.on (/Users/abshahin/dev/azure-cosmos-db-graph-nodejs-getting-started/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:656:26)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:473:21)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
>       at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)

my code looks like this

```
"use strict";

var Gremlin = require('gremlin-secure');
var config = require("./config");

const client = Gremlin.createClient(
    443,
    config.endpoint,
    {
        "session": false,
        "ssl": true,
        "user": `/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`,
        "password": config.primaryKey
    });

client.execute("g.addV('employee').property('id', 'abshahin')", { }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

  });
```

and this is my config

```
var config = {}

config.endpoint = "xxxxxxxx.graphs.azure.com";
config.primaryKey = "super secret key";
config.database = "dbname"
config.collection = "collectionName"

module.exports = config;
```

I contacted Microsoft and they advised to post here, any help.

Comment: I took your code and cannot reproduce your issue on my side. Can you tell us which version of `gremlin-secure` you are using?

Comment: @AaronChen it seems it was a problem in Azure end, it works for me too now, thanks anyway to help out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the url of the db looks like xxx.graphs.azure.com the ulr displayed in the azure portal was not correct in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit similar to [a problem I faced recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450559/mongo-shell-can-not-connect-to-azure-cosmosdb/47450834). Make sure you have latest OpenSSL version

```
openssl version -a
```

Azure CosmosDB enforces SSL/TLS 1.2 which is not supported by older versions of OpenSSL