# Mongoshell unable to connect to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb, mongo-shell, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm looking to migrate data referencing this demo (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/using-mongodb-tools-with-azure-cosmos-db/) and I'm unable to connect to cosmos through mongo shell.

I suspect its an issue with SSL or the server/shell versions but I'm not clear what the fix is. I followed the demo to the T and passed the `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` option along with the auth creds and executed in the correct directory.

Here's what I'm seeing in mongoshell, please advise on troubleshooting tips.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default download for v3.2 from MongoDB site will not have support for SSL (not sure why  ).   You need to select the Windows 64-bit version from the OS dropdown box (screenshot below) to get SSL support.

Another way to verify is that the msi executable name contains ssl (i.e. https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.22-signed.msi )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to downgrade your mongo db version to 3.4.X.

[image]

Then follow the steps from the video and get your mongo shell connect string.

[image]

Connect successfully.

[image]

Also,you could refer to this case:[Mongo shell can not connect to Azure CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450559/mongo-shell-can-not-connect-to-azure-cosmosdb).

Same steps can't be done with Mongo DB 4.0 version,you could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to get the official reply from comsos db team.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to reach out to Microsoft directly and speak to someone via their askcosmosmongoapi@microsoft.com support inbox. An engineer in that distro told me the mongoshell version 3.4 I had installed didnt support SSL. So I had to actually downgrade again to version 3.2 which apparently does support SSL.